# splitlines of quote splits '\n' in sub-quote

Tags: python

Given I have a quote that contains a double sub-quote with a '\n',
If one performs a splitlines on the parent quote, the child quote is split too.

```
double_quote_in_simple_quote = 'v\n"x\ny"\nz'
print(double_quote_in_simple_quote.splitlines())
```

Resulting output

```
['v', '"x', 'y"', 'z']
```

I would have expected the following:

```
['v', '"x\ny"', 'z']
```

Because the '\n' is in the scope of the sub-quote.

I was hoping to get an explanation why it behaves as such and if you have any alternative to 'splitlines' at the level of the main quote only?

Thank you

Comment: Your newline is literal in your original string, which is to say, your string's representation in memory contains an _actual newline_, not the character backslash followed by the character `n`); you'd have to use a raw string (or further quote your backslash) for the backslash to be literal itself instead of part of the syntax that represents a newline literal. That would be something like `r'"x\ny"'`.

Comment: ...anyhow, if you want quote-aware splitting, use `shlex.split()`, not `splitlines()`.

Comment: Try it yourself: `print('"x\ny"')`, and you'll see that there's a newline there already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `split` function doesn't care about additional levels of quoting; it simply splits on every occurrence of the character you split on. (There isn't really a concept of nested quoting; a string is a string, and may or may not contain literal quotes, which are treated the same as any other character.)

If you want to implement quoting inside of strings, you have to do it yourself.

Perhaps use a regular expression;

```py
import re

tokens = re.findall(r'"[^"]*"|[^"]*', double_quote_in_simple_quote)
splitresult = [
    x if x.startswith('"') else x.split('\n') 
    for x in tokens]
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/lAgJTb

Comment: I was hoping the splitlines would split lines of a string according to its content. The regex approach sounds attractive but I might have to find a more optimized approach.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the nature of escape sequences in Python.

`\n` in python means a new line character. Whenever this sequence is captured by python, it treats it as line breakers and considers skipping a line. `splitlines()` method splits a string into a list and the splitting is done at line breaks. That's why you get a list without new line character.

However, you can get away with it by specifying a parameter which won't consider the escape line by default :

```
print(double_quote_in_simple_quote.splitlines(keepends=True))
>>> ['"x\\ny"']
```

Comment: print(double_quote_in_simple_quote.splitlines(keepends=True)) gives me ['"x\n', 'y"'], it still splits the sub-quote.

Comment: Can you give an exact demonstration of when you want to split? It's kind of confusing you are using split but you want the same output as before. What's the use of splitting then.

Comment: You're right, I enriched my example. Let me know if it better highlights the purpose

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a nasty code that can get you around while you try to find another method that splits quotes without the characteristics that makes Python's behaves as it does.

```
double_quote_in_simple_quote = '"x\ny"'

double_quote_in_simple_quote = double_quote_in_simple_quote.replace("\n", "$n")

splitted_quote = double_quote_in_simple_quote.splitlines()
print(splitted_quote)

splitted_quote_decoded = [quote.replace('$n', '\n') for quote in splitted_quote]


print(splitted_quote_decoded)
```

The idea is to replace the \n by something not meaningful yet not used, and then reverse it. I used your example, but I'm sure you will be able to tune it to fit your needs. My output was:

```
['"x$ny"']
['"x\ny"']
```

Comment: I've enriched my example to show that I want to keep the escape lines which are inside the quote but outside the sub-quote. This method would therefore not be valid anymore.

Comment: still, maybe this approach could be useful

Answer (score 1):

If you double-quote a string in Python, that doesn't mean there are nested strings, per se. Whatever the outermost quotes are, Python will start and end the string object according to that. Any internal quote-like characters are treated as the ascii characters.

```
>>> print('dog')
dog
>>> print('"dog"')
"dog"
```

Note how in the second line, the quotes are also printed, because those actual quote-characters are a part of the string. No nesting happening.